# Having multiple sliders under one navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I have a navigation set up where whenever you click on a certain part of the navigation a different section will appear.

I am unfortunately working in HTML 4 and cant seem to find the right sliders to work for this.

Below is an image of the two sliders id like to accomplish, Slider 1 is a product slider and slider two is a vertical slider containing different videos. With our CMS these all just have to be images that when you click will change the Featured video you see larger on the page. then when you click the featured video, a "PrettyPhoto" video will pop up and play.

[image]

Here is the code i have been using:

```
            <!-- + HEADER -->
            <div class="top-message-container">
                <div class="inner-container">
                    <div class="topHeroImage">
                        <img src="images/core_head_logo.png" alt="Evans '56 Calftone">
                        <div class="header_intro_text">Get started by choosing your instrument below</b>.
                        </div>
                    </div>  

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- - END HEADER -->               



            <!-- + NAVIGATION ... -->
            <div class="navigation-container">
                <div class="inner-container">
                    <a href="#1"><img src="images/guitar_bass-icon.png"></a> <a href="#2"><img src="images/percussion-icon.png"></a> <a href="#3"><img src="images/orchestral-icon.png"></a> <a href="#4"><img src="images/woodwinds-icon.png"></a>         
                </div>  


                <div class="main-video-container">
                    <div class="fret_vids" id="1">
                        <div class="videoPlayer" id="video1" style="display: none;">
                            <div class="video-playlist">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video1');" class="video_btn_1 selected"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video2');" class="video_btn_2"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video3');" class="video_btn_3"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video4');" class="video_btn_4"></a><br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="video-image">
                                <a href="http://youtu.be/R3O7if2Koks?list=PLnWoocIzrCpDJBVXJqJnB5iJE66Owoxbg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="http://www.daddario.com/resources/newsletters/heavyweight/heavyweight_video_intro.jpg" alt="Intro Video"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="videoPlayer" id="video2" style="display: none">
                            <div class="video-playlist">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video1');" class="video_btn_1"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video2');" class="video_btn_2 selected"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video3');" class="video_btn_3"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video4');" class="video_btn_4"></a><br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="video-image">
                                <a href="http://youtu.be/xWbZuje4LAc?list=PLnWoocIzrCpDJBVXJqJnB5iJE66Owoxbg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="http://www.daddario.com/resources/newsletters/heavyweight/heavyweight_video_round_1.jpg" alt="Round 1 Video"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="videoPlayer" id="video3" style="display: none">
                            <div class="video-playlist">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video1');" class="video_btn_1"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video2');" class="video_btn_2"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video3');" class="video_btn_3 selected"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video4');" class="video_btn_4"></a><br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="video-image">
                                <a href="http://youtu.be/5O2zaA02c_Y?list=PLnWoocIzrCpDJBVXJqJnB5iJE66Owoxbg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="http://www.daddario.com/resources/newsletters/heavyweight/heavyweight_video_round_2.jpg" alt="Round 2 Video"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="videoPlayer" id="video4" style="display:">
                            <div class="video-playlist">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video1');" class="video_btn_1"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video2');" class="video_btn_2"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video3');" class="video_btn_3"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video4');" class="video_btn_4 selected"></a><br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="video-image">
                                <a href="http://youtu.be/HKYInO4T4T4" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="http://www.daddario.com/resources/newsletters/heavyweight/heavyweight_video_round_3.jpg" alt="Round 3 Video"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="perc_vids" id="2">
                        <div class="videoPlayer" id="video1" style="display: none;">
                            <div class="video-playlist">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video1');" class="video_btn_1 selected"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video2');" class="video_btn_2"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video3');" class="video_btn_3"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video4');" class="video_btn_4"></a><br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="video-image">
                                <a href="http://youtu.be/R3O7if2Koks?list=PLnWoocIzrCpDJBVXJqJnB5iJE66Owoxbg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="http://www.daddario.com/resources/newsletters/heavyweight/heavyweight_video_intro.jpg" alt="Intro Video"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="videoPlayer" id="video2" style="display: none">
                            <div class="video-playlist">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video1');" class="video_btn_1"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video2');" class="video_btn_2 selected"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video3');" class="video_btn_3"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video4');" class="video_btn_4"></a><br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="video-image">
                                <a href="http://youtu.be/xWbZuje4LAc?list=PLnWoocIzrCpDJBVXJqJnB5iJE66Owoxbg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="http://www.daddario.com/resources/newsletters/heavyweight/heavyweight_video_round_1.jpg" alt="Round 1 Video"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="videoPlayer" id="video3" style="display: none">
                            <div class="video-playlist">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video1');" class="video_btn_1"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video2');" class="video_btn_2"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video3');" class="video_btn_3 selected"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video4');" class="video_btn_4"></a><br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="video-image">
                                <a href="http://youtu.be/5O2zaA02c_Y?list=PLnWoocIzrCpDJBVXJqJnB5iJE66Owoxbg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="http://www.daddario.com/resources/newsletters/heavyweight/heavyweight_video_round_2.jpg" alt="Round 2 Video"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="videoPlayer" id="video4" style="display:">
                            <div class="video-playlist">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video1');" class="video_btn_1"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video2');" class="video_btn_2"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video3');" class="video_btn_3"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video4');" class="video_btn_4 selected"></a><br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="video-image">
                                <a href="http://youtu.be/HKYInO4T4T4" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="http://www.daddario.com/resources/newsletters/heavyweight/heavyweight_video_round_3.jpg" alt="Round 3 Video"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="orch_vids" id="3">
                        <div class="videoPlayer" id="video1" style="display: none;">
                            <div class="video-playlist">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video1');" class="video_btn_1 selected"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video2');" class="video_btn_2"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video3');" class="video_btn_3"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video4');" class="video_btn_4"></a><br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="video-image">
                                <a href="http://youtu.be/R3O7if2Koks?list=PLnWoocIzrCpDJBVXJqJnB5iJE66Owoxbg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="http://www.daddario.com/resources/newsletters/heavyweight/heavyweight_video_intro.jpg" alt="Intro Video"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="videoPlayer" id="video2" style="display: none">
                            <div class="video-playlist">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video1');" class="video_btn_1"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video2');" class="video_btn_2 selected"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video3');" class="video_btn_3"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video4');" class="video_btn_4"></a><br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="video-image">
                                <a href="http://youtu.be/xWbZuje4LAc?list=PLnWoocIzrCpDJBVXJqJnB5iJE66Owoxbg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="http://www.daddario.com/resources/newsletters/heavyweight/heavyweight_video_round_1.jpg" alt="Round 1 Video"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="videoPlayer" id="video3" style="display: none">
                            <div class="video-playlist">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video1');" class="video_btn_1"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video2');" class="video_btn_2"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video3');" class="video_btn_3 selected"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video4');" class="video_btn_4"></a><br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="video-image">
                                <a href="http://youtu.be/5O2zaA02c_Y?list=PLnWoocIzrCpDJBVXJqJnB5iJE66Owoxbg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="http://www.daddario.com/resources/newsletters/heavyweight/heavyweight_video_round_2.jpg" alt="Round 2 Video"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="videoPlayer" id="video4" style="display:">
                            <div class="video-playlist">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video1');" class="video_btn_1"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video2');" class="video_btn_2"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video3');" class="video_btn_3"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video4');" class="video_btn_4 selected"></a><br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="video-image">
                                <a href="http://youtu.be/HKYInO4T4T4" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="http://www.daddario.com/resources/newsletters/heavyweight/heavyweight_video_round_3.jpg" alt="Round 3 Video"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="wood_vids" id="4">
                        <div class="videoPlayer" id="video1" style="display: none;">
                            <div class="video-playlist">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video1');" class="video_btn_1 selected"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video2');" class="video_btn_2"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video3');" class="video_btn_3"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video4');" class="video_btn_4"></a><br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="video-image">
                                <a href="http://youtu.be/R3O7if2Koks?list=PLnWoocIzrCpDJBVXJqJnB5iJE66Owoxbg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="http://www.daddario.com/resources/newsletters/heavyweight/heavyweight_video_intro.jpg" alt="Intro Video"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="videoPlayer" id="video2" style="display: none">
                            <div class="video-playlist">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video1');" class="video_btn_1"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video2');" class="video_btn_2 selected"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video3');" class="video_btn_3"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video4');" class="video_btn_4"></a><br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="video-image">
                                <a href="http://youtu.be/xWbZuje4LAc?list=PLnWoocIzrCpDJBVXJqJnB5iJE66Owoxbg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="http://www.daddario.com/resources/newsletters/heavyweight/heavyweight_video_round_1.jpg" alt="Round 1 Video"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="videoPlayer" id="video3" style="display: none">
                            <div class="video-playlist">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video1');" class="video_btn_1"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video2');" class="video_btn_2"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video3');" class="video_btn_3 selected"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video4');" class="video_btn_4"></a><br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="video-image">
                                <a href="http://youtu.be/5O2zaA02c_Y?list=PLnWoocIzrCpDJBVXJqJnB5iJE66Owoxbg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="http://www.daddario.com/resources/newsletters/heavyweight/heavyweight_video_round_2.jpg" alt="Round 2 Video"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="videoPlayer" id="video4" style="display:">
                            <div class="video-playlist">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video1');" class="video_btn_1"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video2');" class="video_btn_2"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video3');" class="video_btn_3"></a><br />
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseUp="chooseTab('video4');" class="video_btn_4 selected"></a><br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="video-image">
                                <a href="http://youtu.be/HKYInO4T4T4" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="http://www.daddario.com/resources/newsletters/heavyweight/heavyweight_video_round_3.jpg" alt="Round 3 Video"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="prod-slider-container">
                    <div class="slider_header_text" id="1"><b>LIKE WHAT YOU SAW?</b> Purchase the products seen in the videos.</div>                        
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- - END NAVIGATION ... -->
```

And here is the CSS i have been using:

```
.page-container {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
left: 0px;
}
.inner-container {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}







/* TOP MESSAGE */
.top-message-container {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
min-height: 360px;
//min-height: 655px;
background-color: #ff0000;
//background-image: url(images/core_header.jpg);
background-position: center bottom;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
overflow: hidden;
}

.topHeroImage {
position: relative;
//display: inline-block;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 95px;
//margin-left: -350px;}


.header_intro_text
{
width: 700px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
font-family: sans-serif;
color: white;
//line-height: 24px;
font-size: 30px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}


/* VIEW STATUS ... */
.navigation-container {
width: 100%;
min-height: 610px;
background-color: #e70000;
display: inline-block;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.navigation-container a
{
color: #ffffff;
padding-left: 50px;
padding-right: 50px;
}

.navigation-container  .inner-container {
color: #58595b;
min-height: 50px;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}


.main-video-container
{
width: 100%;
min-height: 611px;
//background-image: url(images/core_header.jpg);    
background: #ffffff;
position: relative;
overflow-x: hidden;

}






 .fret_vids
 {
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
//background-color: #000000;
//height: 610px;
display: inline-block;
width:100%;}

.fret_vids_2
{
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  //background-color: #000000;
  //height: 610px;
  margin-top: 305px;
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
 }  


.fret_vids img
{
margin-left: -27px;
}

.fret_vids_2 img
{
margin-left: -27px;
}


.perc_vids
{
 text-align: center;
 left: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 //background-color: red;
 //height: 610px;
 display: inline-block;
 width:100%;
 }

.orch_vids
{
 text-align: center;
 left: 200%;
 position: absolute;
 //background-color: purple;
 //height: 610px;
 display: inline-block;
 width:100%;
 }

.wood_vids
{
  text-align: center;
  left: 300%;
  position: absolute;
  //color: white;
  //height: 610px;
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
}


/* VIDEO SECTION ... 
.detailed-reports-container
{
    display: ;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 674px;
    background-color: #000000;
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    text-align: center;
}

.detailed-reports-container .inner-container {
    width: 970px;
}
*/

/* PRODUCT SECTION */
.prod-slider-container {
width: 100%;
min-height: 216px;
background-color: #ffffff;
background-position: center top;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
text-align: center;
}

.slider_header_text
{
font-family: sans-serif;
padding-top: 15px;
color: #58595b;
line-height: 24px;
font-size: 15px;
letter-spacing: 1px;    
}


/*video*/

.videoPlayer {
position: relative;
width: 970px;
height: 476px;    }

.video-playlist {
    position: absolute;
top: 285px;
    left: 15px;
}


.video-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 42px;
    left: 408px;
}


/*video*/
```

Comment: You've got a lot of code to look through here. Could you trim it down to just the relevant code? Or better yet, could you create a CodePen or JSFiddle with this code so we can see it live?

Comment: Also, could you be more specific about what's not working?

Comment: no problem, will put something together.

Comment: @RobertAKARobin does this work? : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yaEGmp

Comment: @RobertAKARobin   so i am an extreme beginner at this. I am trying to create a navigation that contains a "featured video" and a slider next to it to go through the other videos to choose from. i would also like a slider below the video slider in the same section that comes up when you click the specific navigation that holds products. I dont have enough points on here to start a chat or i would. im sorry my terminology is terrible.

Comment: Here is the site kind of functioning from its host: http://assets.daddario.com/core_landing_tst/core_landing_page.html

Comment: No worries about being a beginner! That said, StackOverflow's a great resource when you're getting an error and don't know how to solve it, but is less useful when you're not sure how to start. I'd recommend Googling "navigation carousel library" so you don't have to re-invent the wheel. This one looks neat: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: @RobertAKARobin Thanks so much! this is a great one for sure! i will check it out and try and implement!

Comment: @RobertAKARobin I ended up doing away with the product slider and just kept the video slider. i decided to also do a long page with ID tags to each section so that it functions easier on our CMS. the problem i am running into now is that i finally got the video slider to work but then when i use it again with the same styles and such in the next slice it doesnt function. do you know why that would be? here is a link http://assets.daddario.com/core_landing_tst/core_landing_page.html

Comment: What part doesn't function, Emily? It's a big page and I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: Sorry @RobertAKARobin the part that doesnt work is the video side slider in the other sections other than the guitar and Bass Section.  For some reason in the other sections the slider has lost all functionality and the arrows up  and down are completely gone.

Comment: I'm going to add this below so I can format code better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue is you have multiple things with the `id` of `"carousel"`.
>   An ID is like a Social Security Number or a fingerprint: it's unique.
>   You should only have one element with a given ID. If you find yourself
>   using many IDs, try a `class` instead.

The issue is you have multiple things with the `id` of `"carousel"`. An ID is like a Social Security Number or a fingerprint: it's unique. You should only have one element with a given ID.

If you find yourself using many IDs, try a `class` instead. You select these in jQuery with `.`, same as in CSS.

For instance, to make everything with the `class` of "mycarousel" into a carousel:

```
<div id="foo" class="mycarousel"></div>
<div id="bar" class="mycarousel some-optional-other-class"></div>
```

---

```
<script>
$(".mycarousel").jcarousel("...")
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! i just fixed it and everything is functioning! Now i just need to stylize everything to make it look pretty! you've been a huge help and a lifesaver!